# I can not change the ciphers in OpenBSD 6.2 in httpd.conf

Tags: openbsd, bsd, openbsd-httpd

I can not change the ciphers in OpenBSD 6.2 in httpd.conf

```
    tls ciphers "HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!SSLv3:!TLSv1:!DSS:!ECDSA:!RSA:!SHA1:!AES128:!DHE:-ECDH:ECDHE:+SHA384:+SHA256"
```

> /etc/httpd.conf:46: server "domain.ex": tls configuration mismatch on same address/port

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

Can you show your full configuration? The following starts without error for me on OpenBSD 6.2. Notably the `tls` must be within a `server` block, and must be listed individually for each option. (Yes, this is my mail server and a host build system...)

```
buildsrv_ip="10.11.12.13"

chroot "/home/httpd"

server "default" {
    directory auto index
    listen on $buildsrv_ip tls port 9999
    tls ciphers "HIGH:!eNULL:!SSLv3:!TLSv1:!DSS:!ECDSA:!RSA:!SHA1:!AES128:!DHE:-
ECDH:ECDHE:+SHA384:+SHA256"
    tls certificate "/etc/mail/host.crt"
    tls key "/etc/mail/host.key"
}
```

Comment: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=rootbsd.at

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. It must be in the server "domain.at" block and in the server "default" block also! Otherwise it displays tls configuration mismatch. https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=rootbsd.at